# Cypress Test - Cucumber feature files giving error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file" while running cypress tests in typescript

Tags: typescript, testing, webpack, cucumber, cypress

I am running a cucumber feature file in a cypress runner.

*db.feature*

```
Feature: DB

    Scenario: db test
        When i try to connect to db
        Then i get the code
```

My step definitions are as follows

*db.ts*

```
import { Given, When, Then, Before } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";

When(/^i try to connect to db$/, () => {
  cy.task('log', 'This is the config task')

});

Then(/^i get the code$/, () => {
    return true;
});
```

my *index.js* file under plugins folder is

```
const browserify = require('@cypress/browserify-preprocessor');
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  const options = {
    ...browserify.defaultOptions,
    typescript: require.resolve('typescript'),
  };

  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber(options));
};

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    log(message) {
      console.log(message)

      return null
    },
  })
}
```

I have come across some solutions which use webpack-preprocessor but i am not using webpack-preprocessor but instead using browserify-preprocessor with typescript. (Gave the webpack-preprocessor a try as well but to no avail.)

When i run this in the cypress runner i get the following error
[image]

When i remove the config task, log, from the `index.js` file and comment out the `cy.task` call in the `db.ts` file the code works smoothly. Its only when i add a config task in the `index.js`  file that i get the following error.

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/integration/db.feature 3:17
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| Feature: DB
| 
>     Scenario: db test
|         When i try to connect to db
|         Then i get the code
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-preprocessor\dist\index.js:180:23)
    at C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:99:9
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Watching._done (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:98:28)
    at C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:73:19
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:499:39)
    at C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:54:20
    at C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:482:27
    at C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
    at done (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:464:33
    at C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:143:16
    at C:\Users\visha\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.3\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:61:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)
```

This is my package.json

```
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber",
      "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
      "nonGlobalStepBaseDir": "cypress/support/step_definitions"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cosmiconfig": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/browserify-preprocessor": "^3.0.2",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.11.1",
    "@types/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.0.1",
    "cypress": "^9.5.3",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fix was having the custom task under the same module.export as the browserify. Having two differed module.export in the `index.js` file caused issue.

This is my final `index.js` file

```
const browserify = require('@cypress/browserify-preprocessor');
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  const options = {
    ...browserify.defaultOptions,
    typescript: require.resolve('typescript'),
  };

  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber(options));
  on('task', {
    log(message) {
      console.log(message)

      return null
    },
  })
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, but in my case the solution was to pass the content of the plugin/index.js into `setupNodeEvents` from `cypress.config.ts` file.

I'm using cypress 10.0.0 version and based on the oficial [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#setupNodeEvents), the plugins file was deprecated.

```
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
      const browserify = require('@cypress/browserify-preprocessor');
      const options = {
        ...browserify.defaultOptions,
        typescript: require.resolve('typescript'),
      };
      on('file:preprocessor', cucumber(options));
    },
   ...
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need browserify to run tests with cucumber.

Add below code in cypress.config.js file

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const browserify = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/browserify");

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on("file:preprocessor", browserify.default(config));

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config;
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
});
```

Add the below dependency in package.json

```
  "@cypress/browserify-preprocessor": "latest"
```

In step add this line

```
import { Given, When, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
```

Install the dependency again using npm i

and execute your test. It will work !